# Formula for an exponent

Tags: real-analysis, exponentiation

Is there a formula for $n$ in an equation of the form:

$$a^n+b^n=c$$

where $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$? Is there any theorem that say something about this kind of a problem?

EDIT: Second version is if  $n \in \mathbb{R}$ instead of  $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

For any given $c$ and $n$, the points $(a,b)$ such that $a^n + b^n = c$ form a curve in the $a-b$ plane (of course if $n$ is even you'll need $c > 0$ for this to be nonempty).  The union of these curves for $n \in \mathbb N$ will have Lebesgue measure $0$, and thus miss almost every point of that plane.  So in general the problem can't be solved for $n \in \mathbb N$.

Here are the curves in the first quadrant for $c=1$ and $n=1$ to $10$.  As $n \to \infty$ the curves approach the polygonal curve $[0,1]$ to $[1,1]$ to $[1,0]$.

[image]

Comment: How does the fact that it misses almost every point of that plane imply that there is no formula?

Comment: What doesn't exist doesn't have a formula.

Comment: Now if you asked for $n \in \mathbb R$ (with $a, b, c > 0$) you'd have a reasonable question.  However, the answer would be that there is no known general formula.

Comment: If the more interesting question is if $n \in \mathbb{R}$ then I'm going to change the question.